# Looking for duplicates based on a few other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the rows where `PilotID` has used the `shimpmentNumber` more than once.

I have this so far.

```
select f_Shipment_ID
      ,f_date
      ,f_Pilot_ID
      ,f_Shipname
      ,f_SailedFrom
      ,f_SailedTo
      ,f_d_m
      ,f_Shipmentnumber
      ,f_NumberOfPilots
from t_shipment
where f_Pilot_ID < 10000 
  and f_NumberOfPilots=1
  and f_Shipmentnumber in(select f_Shipmentnumber 
                          from t_shipment
                          group by f_Shipmentnumber
                          Having count(*) >1)
```

Comment: So what is the issue with your SQL?  Please provide some sample data, the current output and expected output.

Comment: I need to narrow it down to  just rows where a pilot has used the same shimpment number more than once. Different pilots can use the same ID but only once.

Comment: f_Shipment_ID f_date f_Pilot_ID f_Shipname f_SailedFrom f_SailedTo f_d_m f_Shipmentnumber f_NumberOfPilots
115141 2014-01-14 05:45:00.000 228 SEAOATH Alfa/4 -- P/B Korsør -- P/B 8.50 307203 1
114976 2014-01-14 08:00:00.000 63 SEAOATH Korsør -- P/B Gedser NE -- P/B 8.50 307203 1
115655 2014-01-21 12:00:00.000 228 DS WARRIOR Bornholm  -- P/B STS-operations Off Frederikshavn 14.40 307205 1

Comment: Uh... select f_pilot_id, f_shipmentnumber, count( * ) from t_shipment group by f_pilot_id, f_shipmentnumber having count( * ) > 1

Comment: @robertwoods It is better to add the sample data and further details to the question by using the edit link rather than the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
-- The CTE determines the f_Pilot_ID/f_Shipmentnumber combinations that appear more than once.
with DuplicateShipmentNumberCTE as
(
    select
        f_Pilot_ID,
        f_Shipmentnumber
    from
        t_shipment
    where
        f_Pilot_ID < 10000 and
        f_NumberOfPilots = 1
    group by
        f_Pilot_ID,
        f_Shipmentnumber
    having
        count(1) > 1
)

select
    Shipment.f_Shipment_ID,
    Shipment.f_date,
    Shipment.f_Pilot_ID,
    Shipment.f_Shipname,
    Shipment.f_SailedFrom,
    Shipment.f_SailedTo,
    Shipment.f_d_m,
    Shipment.f_Shipmentnumber,
    Shipment.f_NumberOfPilots
from
    -- The join is used to restrict the result set to the shipments identified by the CTE.
    t_shipment Shipment
    inner join DuplicateShipmentNumberCTE CTE on
        Shipment.f_Pilot_ID = CTE.f_Pilot_ID and
        Shipment.f_Shipmentnumber = CTE.f_Shipmentnumber
where
    f_NumberOfPilots = 1;
```

You can also do this with a subquery if you want to—or if you're using an old version of SQL Server that doesn't support [CTEs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)—but I find the CTE syntax to be more natural, if only because it enables you to read and understand the query from the top down, rather than from the inside out.

Answer (score 1):

In your sub select use:

```
select f_Shipmentnumber 
                      from t_shipment
                      group by f_pilot_id, f_Shipmentnumber
                      Having count(*) >1
```

Comment: that is helping but I  think I'm still getting a lot of junk

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
select f_Shipment_ID
      ,f_date
      ,f_Pilot_ID
      ,f_Shipname
      ,f_SailedFrom
      ,f_SailedTo
      ,f_d_m
      ,f_Shipmentnumber
      ,f_NumberOfPilots
from t_shipment
where f_Pilot_ID < 10000 
  and f_NumberOfPilots=1
  and f_Pilot_ID  IN (select f_Pilot_ID 
                          from t_shipment
                          group by f_Pilot_ID, f_Shipmentnumber
                          Having count(*) >1)
```